# Is there a way to create a method for a generic collection of a custom class in C#?

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I was wondering if this was at all possible. Since I´m not all right there with IEnumerator/IEnumerables, there might be a way to do it I don´t know.
I imagine it would go something like this:

```
public namespace cookietest
{
    public static class Program{
        public List<Cookie> cookies = new List<Cookie>();
        CookieJar cookieJar = cookies.ToCookieJar();
    }

    public class Cookie{
        public int size;
        //Implementatin of ToCookieJar()
    }
}
```

I understand that there are better design solutions and that this isn't *really* a problem, but I got curious and couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: What would you expect `CookieJar` to be?

Comment: Are you looking for [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)?

Comment: I imagine the return type could be anything, I just made up something. Maybe a better example would have been a method that returned a Cookie object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Given a reference type, such as `List<T>`, you can "extend" it with your own methods like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public List<Cookie> cookies = new List<Cookie>();
    CookieJar cookieJar = cookies.ToCookieJar();
}

public class Cookie
{
    public int size;
}

public static class CookieExtensions
{
    public static CookieJar ToCookieJar(this IEnumerable<Cookie> list)
    {
        return new CookieJar(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay that's true, the OP will have to fill in how `CookieJar` is constructed. The point was to illustrate how an extension method is declared.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay ah, saw the mixup with `Cookie` class. I would place the extension method in a separate class, such as `CookieExtensions`.

Comment: This is pretty amazing, I didn't even know about extension methods. Are they a good solution or is some other workaround preferred?

Comment: @jchang based on what little context you have provided in the question: no. This is what extension methods are for, "adding" methods to externally declared types that you cannot change the internals of... I also use them sometimes to add helper or shorthand methods to types so to keep the extended types cleaner.